# Can I use gtk_main() in main function and subfunction?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I will write a main function and a subfunction. Both of them will construct a `GtkWindow`. I want to implement a situation where the `GtkWindow` in subfunction will be destroyed first if I pess `GtkButton` in this window. When the subfunction returns, the main function will construct a `GtkWindow`. So how should I do? Should I use `gtk_main` in subfunction and main function?

Comment: You should only run one main loop. Then use callbacks to make it do things in response to input. Please check a basic guide like [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk3-General.description) for examples of how to use signals and callbacks. If you still have a specific question, please show your current code and describe what you want to change it to do.

Comment: This my code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296540/why-does-the-subfunction-not-destroy-the-gtkwindow

Comment: So this is a duplicate of that and should be closed accordingly.